# Interface reference does not find expected class

Tags: c#, interface

I'm quite new to programming in general and I have run into a problem when trying to understand and use interfaces in C#.

I have a GUI class, called MainWindow. The class implements a interface called IClientView. Another class, ClientController, uses this interface to update the fields within MainWindow.

However, it does not work as I expected, as the reference to my interface is always null within ClientController, and I don't understand why.

Here is parts of the code, any help is appreciated.

```
class ClientController : IClientController
{
    public IClientView ViewForm { get; set; }
}

public interface IClientView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the status window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status">Updates the status view.</param>
    void StatusWindow(string status);
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, ILoginFormView, IClientView
{
    #region IClientView implementation

    public void StatusWindow(string status)
    {
        clientInfoTextBlock.Text += status +"\n";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

EDIT:

I should add that I have another interface, which is going to handle logins, referenced in the same way by the ClientController class and implemented by the MainWindow class and that one works. I just can't figure out the difference between the two:

```
class ClientController: IClientController 
{
    #region private fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to login form
    /// </summary>
    public ILoginFormView LoginForm 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public interface ILoginFormView 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IP address of server to connect to
    /// </summary>
    string ServerIpAddress 
    {
        get;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TCP port number of server to connect to
    /// </summary>
    int ServerTcpPort 
    {
        get;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow: Window, ILoginFormView, IClientView 
{
    #region ILoginFormView implementation

    /// <summary>
    /// IP address of server to connect to.
    /// </summary>
    public string ServerIpAddress 
    {
        get 
        {
            return (string) Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<string>( () => serverAddressBox.Text));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TCP port of the server to connect to.
    /// </summary>
    public int ServerTcpPort 
    {
        get 
        {
             return (int) Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<int>( () => Convert.ToInt32(serverPortBox.Text)));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Code Snippet is not for C#. It is for JS / HTML / CSS.

Comment: Post `ClientController.ViewForm` initialization code, please.

Comment: @Dennis I suspect there is no initialization, which is the problem.

Comment: @PeterSchneider [Introducing Runnable **JavaScript, CSS, and HTML** Code Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean w. the initialization code on the ClientController side, but as far as I can tell I have done the same as w. the ILoginFormView interface, and that one works.

Comment: In `ClientController` you declare a `ILoginFormView` instance and a `IClientView` instance. Neither of them will work if you don't initialize them by some means (`ViewForm = new ...`). What is working is the `ILoginFormView` implementation in `MainWindow`, which is a different thing.

Comment: @PatriceGahide: Thank you! Turned out that I had forgotten that I initialize the ILoginForm already in the App.xaml.cs class... It all works now. Thank you everyone!

Comment: This should be marked as answered. Can I do that somehow?

Comment: Patrice should create an answer and then you can select that as the right answer. These are just comments to the question and you can't select a comment as the answer.